# Not getting a notification when trying to use real-time database communications

Tags: database, real-time, backand

I'm trying to use web sockets to add a new notification to my app. I'm using Backand as my server, and can't seem to get a grasp on responding to the new event. Here's my server side code to send the event:

```
//Action: Update - After data saved and committed 
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {  
   //Send to array of users   
   socket.emitUsers("new_notification",userInput, ["admins"]);
  return {}; 
}
```

And my client code to receive it:

```
//Wait for server updates on 'items' object 
Backand.on('new_notification', function (data) {   
  //Get the 'items' object that have changed   
  console.log(data);
});
```

But when I try to receive the event in my app code, I never see a notification of type "new_notification". Can someone please let me know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using emitRole instead of emitUsers. The code above emits to a user array, but it looks like you want to send a notification to the "admins" role. Change this to emitRole() and you should be ok.

Comment: And how can I set it to users instead?

Comment: Ohh, now I get it. Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For role you want to keep it case sensitive so it will be:
socket.emitRole("items_updated",userInput, "Admin");

For users the syntax is:
socket.emitUsers("items_updated",userInput, ["user2@gmail.com","user1@gmail.com"]);